# Table row on Android 6 is not taking 100% width

Tags: android, html, css, html-table, html-email

I have the code below used in an html email and it's working as expected in all email clients, except Android 6.0 Gmail! the blue contact us button is not taking 100% of the width.

Any thoughts?

First screenshot shows how it looks like on real device, while the second one is from litmus which is not correct, but this is what I'm trying to make look like.

[image: Check screenshot here]

[image: This is how Litmus show but in reality its not]

The code:

```css
.cta {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:414px) {
  .mobile {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<table class="mobile" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#00a5c9; font-weight: normal;">
      <tr>
        <td class="cta" style="text-align: left; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; padding: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; vertical-align: top; line-height: normal !important;">
          <a style="text-align: left; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">CONTACT US</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/25/0f0" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code you posted does not match the images you posted. It would be helpful to share your html code.

Comment: you mean the gray box at the bottom? its not helpful to include it in the code. its just another `<tr></tr>` @gwally

Comment: The table you posted is wrapped in `<tr>` tags. The parent table is missing. Post your full html code so we can help you.

Comment: There you go! I just added the parent of this `<tr>` @gwally. thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way around this is the force Android 5.1 & 6.0 to display the desktop version of your email. The code snippet below needs a 600x1 transparent png to act as a full width spacer. This spacer will be hidden on all mobile clients that support media queries and allow the mobile view to render.

```
  <tr style="line-height: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" class="mobilehide">
    <td align="center" style="min-width:600px;font-size:1px; line-height: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
      <img src="images/android-spacer.png" alt="" width="600" height="1" style="display: block;" border="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

This should be added before the closing tag of your outermost table (last one before the closing body)

```
        </td>
      </tr>
    <!-- add here -->
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good way! it's displaying the email in mobile that doesn't support media query like desktop, but what about the `mobilehide` class what properties should I add to it?

Comment: Glad it's helped. Sorry should've mentioned the class, i just use `display:none !important` property, so it'll hide the spacer on all other mobile views

Comment: without this css in the head it wont work for some email clients. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `width: 100%;`, try using `width: 100vw;`

Answer (score 0):

Certain versions of Android and Gmail do not use media queries.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/

This is why the blue contact button only takes up 1/3 of the Android screen, but it takes up 100% of the screen on IOS devices. IOS will respect the media query and Android will use the `width="33%"` from the table:

```
<table class="mobile" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
```

Since you will not post the rest of your code as expected on Stack Overflow, I cannot offer a suggestion for a workaround because I'm not sure what you're trying to do. At least you now know why it isn't working.

Good luck.

Comment: Is there away to get around it? the code is too long to post on here and the rest of it is not effecting this blue button. but I will add more of the code. Thank you

Comment: @Adam, it took hours to convince you to post enough code so we could see what the issue was and come up with an answer. I'm not spending  anymore time trying to convince you the value of Stack Overflow. Good luck finding a solution.